# circular error when trying to import "TENSORFLOW_DATASET"

Tags: python, tensorflow

I get the below error when I try to import tensorflow_dataset

ImportError: cannot import name 'core' from partially initialized module 'tensorflow_datasets' (most likely
due to a circular import) (C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow_datasets_*init*_.py)

knowing that my tesnorflow version is 2.13.0, tensorflow_datasets version is Version: 4.9.2

tried to unistall and install again and didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem :'ImportError: cannot import name 'core' from partially initialized module 'tensorflow_datasets' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\Usuario\miniconda3\envs\tf213\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_datasets_*init*_.py)'